# How do i create "generation" sequences based on map containing element and parent element in Scala?

Tags: scala, data-structures

I face following problem.

I have this map where key represents an element and the value represents its parent element:

```
Map(
    "a1" -> Some("b1"), 
    "a2" -> Some("b1"), 
    "b1" -> Some("c1"),
    "c1" -> None
)
```

I would need to create something like "generation sequences", which would look something like this:

```
Seq(
    Seq("a1", "b1", "c1"),
    Seq("a2", "b1", "c1")
)
```

How can I do it, especially so I wouldn't left with this:

```
Seq(
    Seq("a1", "b1", "c1"),
    Seq("b1", "c1"),
    Seq("c1"),
    Seq("a2", "b1", "c1"),
    Seq("b1", "c1"),
    Seq("c1")
)
```

Thank you for answers!

Comment: What have you tried? Why didn't it work? A hint, this is pretty easy to solve with recursion, it is just a DFS on a graph. - BTW, why your values are `Option`? That is extremely redundant

Comment: The question needs more clarity in terms of what has been tried and references used.